Limits of subset sequence
I remember reading about this problem elsewhere, but I cannot find it now. The original problem is as below:
Alice and Bob play a game. Let $R_0=R$ be the reals. For each $n\in N$, Alice specifies an infinite subset $R_{2n+1}$ of $R_{2n}$, then Bob specifies an infinite subset $R_{2n+2}$ of $R_{2n+1}$. Afterwards, if Alice can choose a point $a\in R$ that is in the intersection of all $R_{i}, i\in N$, she wins. Otherwise, Bob wins. Find a winning strategy for one of the players.
NB: The subset choosing process is executed by each of the players declaring a subset choosing algorithm, so there can be a well defined output for the infinite process. If you find the final output cannot be specified, then Bob wins in that case.

Take a look at: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/276796/898813

I can only assume by "afterwards", you mean "After Alice and Bob have chosen an infinite sequence of descending sets".
Since you only specify "infinite", not "uncountable" as in the thread schube linked, Bob has an easy winning strategy. On his first turn, his pick is a sequence $\{x_i\}_{i\in\Bbb N}$.All future sets are infinite subsets of this sequence, which makes them subsequences. On his turns, all Bob has to do is throw out the remaining element with the lowest index. This insures that any element $x_{k-1}$ in the sequence will be removed at latest by Bob's $k^\text{th}$ turn.
Since every element of the sequence is removed on or before one of Bob's turns, and all other numbers are removed on his first turn, there will be nothing left at the end. Alice cannot demonstrate a member.

If the rules are changed to require all the sets to be uncountable, then in the thread schube found, Asaf Karagila proves that Bob has no winning strategy. (Note that Bob corresponds to player I in that thread, as there player I is forced to make $\Bbb R$ their first move, with player II making the first reduction. Here $\Bbb R$ is given, and Alice makes the first reduction.) This does not mean Alice has winning strategy either, but if Asaf couldn't find one, I am unlikely to.
